# Alternative software for ABAQUS CAE for running the ABAQUS .inp files

Tags: abaqus

I am running an optimisation problem using Abaqus and Matlab.
Even though I have sufficient hardware resource, but I have limited number of Abaqus license.
I am wondering if there is any other software that can import the Abaqus .inp file and run the file **independent of the Abaqus** so I won't need any Abaqus license.
or any other suggestion that helps me bypass this problem.
Thanks

Comment: You can use any free FE software [available](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_finite_element_software_packages). Obviously, non of them will use Abaqus input file as it is a list of commands/instructions for the Abaqus solver.

Comment: Thanks, but due to complexity of my current model, it takes time to re-model it in any other FEM software. I was hoping for some software and can read abaqus inp file or it would be feasible to make some small changes in the INP files and get result.

Answer (score 0):

"software and can read abaqus inp file or it would be feasible to make some small changes in the INP files"

From Google search, you could try Calculix (https://github.com/calculix/)

For example:

calculix/new keywords (https://github.com/calculix/new_keywords)
"A tool to track new keywords in CalculiX and Abaqus releases. Abaqus keywords are taken from SIMULIA User Assistance. CalculiX keywords are extracted from the official PDF documentation."

calculix/konvertor (https://github.com/calculix/konvertor)
"Convert GMSH ABACUS INP file -> INP file for CGX"